# SPO - Render ListView in XsltListViewWebPart and Query(limit rows to current user)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, xslt-list-view-web-part, xml, schema

I created following listView through Visual Studio in my List on SharePoint-Hosted Add-in project:

[image]

> **Where i created listView - Generated xml like this:**

```
<View BaseViewID="2"
 Name="2930629c-f218-4951-baca-ff0beea837bc"
 DisplayName="My holidays"
 Type="HTML" 
 WebPartZoneID="Main"
 SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx"
 Url="MyHolidays.aspx">
<RowLimit>30</RowLimit>
```

> **I insert This query for current view where show my holidays:**

```
<Query>
   <OrderBy><FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef></OrderBy>
   <Where>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name="Author" />
         <Value Type="User">[Me]</Value>
      </Eq>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

How to render this view in my .asp page?

> **This is my code in default.aspx page, where i need to show My holidays view:**

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server"
    FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ID="full" Title="loc:full">
    <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart ID="XsltListViewWebPart2"
        runat="server" ListUrl="Lists/Holidays" IsIncluded="True"
        NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" Title="Images used in switcher"
        PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW" Default="False"
        ViewContentTypeId="0x" ViewId="2">
    </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

> 1) Is it true my query?
>
> 2) I dont know ViewID="2" is correct to render "My holidays" view.

.